# Magento 2 - Go to checkout button is not clickable

Tags: magento2, checkout, cart, shopping-cart

Site was working fine and then suddenly **"Go to checkout"** buttons in minicart and shopping cart are not clickable. Can't seems to find the reason behind it. Does anyone has any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Magento version 2.3.5-p2

[image]